# How can I write a using block in another way?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, idisposable, using, using-statement

I have a class with different methods from a Windows Form. In my test code, I used this to create a new OpenXML Document:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(docName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
```

But this seems not working on multiple methods. How can I fix it? It won't work without the using, so after a bit of research I found out that this class was IDisposable.

But I have 2 needs right now:

1) If the file exists, the document has to open instead of creating a new one.

2) The docName, which contains the path to the file that he's going to save, has to be reachable end used in the block as seen above.

Is there a way to do this?

This is my code right now:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace WordExample
{
    public partial class Word : Form
    {
        private string _docName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\xxx2.docx";
        private WordprocessingDocument _package;
        private Document _doc;
        private Body _body;

        public Word()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            /*if (File.Exists(_docName))
            {
                _package = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_docName, false);
                _doc = _package.MainDocumentPart.Document;
                _body = _doc.Body;
            }
            else
            {
                _package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(_docName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                _package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                _doc = _package.MainDocumentPart.Document;
                _body = new Body();
            }*/

            _package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(_docName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
            _package.AddMainDocumentPart();
            _doc = new Document();
            _body = new Body();
        }

        private void Word_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAddParagraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            Text t = new Text(txtTekstParagraaf.Text);
            Run r = new Run();
            RunProperties rPr = new RunProperties();
            if (chkBold.Checked)
            {
                Bold b = new Bold();
                rPr.Append(b);
            }
            if (chkItalic.Checked)
            {
                Italic b = new Italic();
                rPr.Append(b);
            }
            if (chkUnderline.Checked)
            {
                Underline b = new Underline();
                rPr.Append(b);
            }
            //RunProperties
            //r.PrependChild<RunProperties>(rPr);
            r.PrependChild(rPr);
            r.AppendChild(t);
            p.AppendChild(r);
            _body.AppendChild(p);*/
            Save();
        }

        private void Save()
        {
            _doc.AppendChild(_body);
            _package.MainDocumentPart.Document = _doc;

            // Save changes to the main document part. 
            _package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

But this code generates an error when trying to open the created document afterwards AND when I try to open an document instead of creating one.

Comment: what do you mean by : butt this seems not working on multiple methods

Answer (score 3):

You can try using *trenary operator* here:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument package = File.Exists(docName) ? 
         WordprocessingDocument.Create(docName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document) :
         WordprocessingDocument.Open(docName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: And is there a way to use the package through multiple methods in one class? 'Cause I don't think you can wrap a using statement around multiple methods?

Comment: you can either pass `package` to these methods as a parameter or make it a member of the class - `package.Dispose` will have to be explicitly called in this case

Comment: two issues here - 1) you should switch file opening and creation 2) that's really hard to read

Answer (score 2):

> If the file exists, the document has to open instead of creating a new one.

So why don't you use an `if` statement?

```
if(File.Exists(docName))
{
    using(var package = ..) // open file
    {
       ...  
    }
}
else
{
   using(var package = ..) // create file
   {
       ...  
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't you write redundant code then? I suppose you'll need the package for the rest of the code too?

Answer (score 1):

You are not forced to instantiate variable directly in using statement. You can move creation to separate method:

```
private WordprocessingDocument GetPackage(string docName)
{
    var docType = WordprocessingDocumentType.Document;

    if (File.Exists(docName))
       return WordprocessingDocument.Open(docName, docType);

    return WordprocessingDocument.Create(docName, docType);
}
```

Now your code will look like:

```
using(var package = GetPackage(docName))
{
   // ...
}
```

---

UPDATE: If you want to reuse disposable dependency in all methods of class (as you stated in comments) you should implement `IDisposale` by class which holds disposable dependency, and dispose that dependency when you are disposing class:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private readonly WordprocessingDocument _package;

    public Foo()
    {
        _package = GetPackage(docName); // implemented as above
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
       // use _package without `using` block
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
       // use _package without `using` block
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_package != null)
            _package.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then wrap instance of `Foo` into `using` block:

```
using(var foo = new Foo()) // _package created here
{
    foo.Method1(); // same _package instance used by both methods
    foo.Method2();
} // _package will be disposed here
```

Comment: As in my code above, can I do something like using(_package) {...} in every method? If I save the real object as a field?

Comment: No, as after the first `using` it will be disposed.

Comment: @OlivierVanBulck no, you can't because instance of packages saved in field will be disposed after first `using`. If you need to reuse package for all methods, you should make your class disposable, don't wrap `_package` in `using` statements, and dispose `_package` in Dispose of class

Comment: My class is already Disposable by the Form which is implemented. But how can I work with that then?

Comment: @OlivierVanBulck I added sample of code which uses _package stored in field